# Subset Relations Between CFGs and Their Languages

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata, context-free

Is it possible for there to exist two context-free grammars where the set of rules of the first is a proper subset of the set of rules of the second, yet the language generated by the second grammar is a proper subset of the language generated by the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ and $H$ be your two context-free grammars, respectively. If the set of all rules in $G$ is a subset of the set of all rules in $H$, then all derivations possible in $G$ are also possible in $H$. In other words, the language accepted by $G$ is also accepted by $H$.

Therefore, it is impossible for the language generated by $H$ to be a proper subset of the language generated by $G$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Adding rules can only add options for generating strings; all preexisting derivations are still possible.

Answer (score 1):

This might be considered cheating, but I think it's possible to define such grammars if the set of terminals/non-terminals isn't required to be the same for both of them.

Using [wikipedias formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Formal_definitions), define the CFGs $G_1 = (V_1, \Sigma_1, R_1, S)$ and $G_2 = (V_2, \Sigma_2, R_2, S)$ such that

- $V_1 = \{S\}$, $V_2 = \{S, A\}$
- $\Sigma_1 = \{A\}$, $\Sigma_2 = \emptyset$
- $R_1 = \{S \to A\} \subset R_2 = \{S \to A, A \to A\}$

then $L(G_1) = \{A\} \supset \emptyset = L(G_2)$.

Comment: How can you define “A” as a non terminal and variable at the same time, isnt it contradicting with definition of CFGs ?

Comment: As @Mocak pointed out, $V_2$ is the set of nonterminals and includes $A$. Therefore, $A$ cannot appear in $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: @ZiadIsmailiAlaoui That's incorrect, $V_2$ is the set of nonterminals **of $G_2$**, so $V_2$ and $\Sigma_2$ must be disjoint.
Being terminal/non-terminal isn't an intrinsic property of symbols, it only makes sense in reference to a specific grammar.

Comment: Then we can say the rule of this teo language is different, cant we? Since the rule in one language uses A as a nonterminal while the other one is terminal

Comment: @Mocak The $A$ in $S \to A$ comes from $\Sigma_1$ in $R_1$ and from $V_2$ in $R_2$, but that doesn't mean that there are two different $A$s.
Would you also consider $5 \in \mathbb{N}$ to be different from $5 \in \mathbb{R}$ because we call it a natural number in the first and a real number in the second case 

Comment: @Knogger However, you wrote the following: $R_1 = \{S \rightarrow A\} \subset R_2 = \{S \rightarrow A, A \rightarrow A\}$. This is only true if $A$ refers to the same object, and one cannot be a terminal and nonterminal simultaneously. Your analogy with natural and real numbers does not work since there exists no overlap between nonterminal and terminal symbols, while natural and real numbers do overlap.

Comment: @ZiadIsmailiAlaoui Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but what you're saying is simply not true.
A symbol cannot be a terminal and a non-terminal **in the same grammar** (and indeed $V_1 \cap \Sigma_1 = V_2 \cap \Sigma_2 = \emptyset$), but that does not mean that $V_2 \cap \Sigma_1 = \emptyset$ must hold.
The terminals/non-terminals of different grammars are free to overlap, they're simply sets without correlation.

Comment: If I define a grammar that uses all alphabetical characters as terminals, does that mean that you now can't use single letter non-terminals in a different grammar?

Comment: @Knogger, I perfectly understand what you are saying; however, if you want to use the symbol $A$, you need to be consistent in your **entire** argument. It is incoherent to posit that $\{S \rightarrow A\} \subset \{S \rightarrow A, A \rightarrow A\}$ when $A$ on the LHS is not equal to $A$ on the RHS. That statement is only true if by $A$, you mean the same thing on both sides (and $S$ too). If $A$ is a nonterminal on the LHS, as defined in $\Sigma_1$, and $A$ is terminal on the RHS, as defined in $V_2$, then we get a contradiction. (Question: Would it be coherent to say $\Sigma_2 = \{S\}$?)

Comment: @ZiadIsmailiAlaoui Being a (non-)terminal isn't a property of symbols, but a label depending on what set a symbol belongs to.
There's only one $A$ (and only one $S$ for that matter), and $A \in \Sigma_1 \cap V_2$ is a terminal of $G_1$ and a non-terminal of $G_2$, it can be both.

$S \to A$ is just a tuple $(S, A)$, and $(S, A) = (S, A)$ independent to which sets $S, A$ might belong to.
There's no difference between $S \to A \in V_1 \times (V_1 \cup \Sigma_1)$ and $S \to A \in V_2 \times (V_2 \cup \Sigma_2)$.
These are just mathematical objects without special meaning.

Comment: $\Sigma_2 = \{S\}$ doesn't make sense since that would imply $V_2 \cap \Sigma_2 \neq \emptyset$, but it's still a coherent mathematical statement.

Comment: @Knogger Symbols carry consistent meaning, and you cannot write a statement such as $\{S \rightarrow A \} = \{S \rightarrow A \}$ when $A$ denotes completely different things on both sides. Suppose I replaced $A$ with $\mathsf{NT}$ and $\mathsf{T}$ when it is a nonterminal and when it is a terminal, respectively. Your statement then reads, $\{S \rightarrow \mathsf{T}\} \subset \{S \rightarrow \mathsf{NT}, \mathsf{NT} \rightarrow \mathsf{NT}\}$—which is incorrect. You cannot have $\Sigma_1 \cap V_2 \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @ZiadIsmailiAlaoui That's the point, $A$ denotes the same object on both sides of the equality.
You can have $\Sigma_1 \cap V_2 \neq \emptyset$, $\Sigma_1$ and $V_2$ don't have any relation to each other.
How do you get to the conclusion that $\Sigma_1$ and $V_2$ must be disjoint?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152056/discussion-between-ziad-ismaili-alaoui-and-knogger).

Comment: I wish I had chance to tag my professor here so he can see how trivial is the question and not appropriate to ask this in midterm.

Comment: Since this is a "type unsoundness" loophole, it may not be present in the definitions across different books. Some authors may phrase it in such a way that happens to rule this out.